# How do I alter a function?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I want to track taxonomy term tagging count in the database; for each taxonomy term, I want a term tagged count that stores the number of nodes using the taxonomy term. I know I can retrieve it with a query on `taxonomy_index` but it is too time consuming for me.

I've found [`taxonomy_build_node_index($node)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_build_node_index/7) and [`taxonomy_delete_node_index($node)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_delete_node_index/7), which are called in [`taxonomy_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_insert/7), [`taxonomy_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_update/7), and [`taxonomy_node_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_delete/7) (node hooks).

I know a form can be altered with `hook_fom_alter()`. Is there a way to alter these functions as well?

Comment: How is a count query on taxonomy_term_index too time consuming? It will be much faster than any of those functions you called up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have a way to generally replace a function in a module with a function implemented by another module.

In the case of hooks, you could alter the output of a hook with another hook, but in your case you don't even need this. Just implement [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x), [`hook_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x), and [`hook_node_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7.x), and add the code necessary for counting the tags used by nodes.

As [said from Jaypan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165099/how-to-alter-a-function-in-drupal-7#comment267220_165099), you don't say in which way querying the *taxonomy_index* table would be too expensive. I am not sure it would be that expensive, since the table saves the taxonomy term IDs and the node IDs: You just need to count the table rows with a specific value for *tid*.

Comment: In my module I need to know count of too many terms for some web mining proposes so lots of queries should be run (one for each term) so I'd rather prefer to have each term count pre calculated.
that's why I believe calling taxonomy_term_index would be time consiuming.